# Organizing preamble while using glossaries package

Tags: sectioning, glossaries, preamble, import

I am currently trying to make a dictionary in LaTeX (using iOS textmaker), and have been using the \usepackage{glossaries}.  The issue I am having is that I have to define my entries in the preamble through \newglossaryentry, and it has gotten rather difficult to navigate.  I am a big fan of using sections and chapters to keep my document clean and easy to navigate, but this is not an option until I begin my document.

I am wondering if:

- there is anything analogous the adding sections into my preamble that I can minimize or expand when needed.
- there is a way to create a separate document/documents where I can define my terms, and import that into my preamble.

I am open to other suggestions too -- let me know what worked for you!

~Breena

---

**Update**

Code for main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}.       %allows usage of glossary
\makenoidxglossaries

\loadglsentries{ch1}           %calls for text file (ch1.tex) with definitions
\loadglsentries{ch2}           %%calls for text file (ch2.tex) with definitions

\begin{document}
\gls{word}.                    %will print the name of the word
\printnoidxglossary[sort=word] %prints the glossary using all definitions called for
\end{document}
```

Code for secondary document with definitions (file name: ch1.tex):

```
\newglossaryentry{word}{name={word name},description={word definition}}
```

Comment: You might want to use `\loadglsentries[<type>]{<filename>}` to load an external file that contains the glossary entry definitions as described in section '4.6 Loading Entries From a File'  of the `glossaries`'s user manual

Comment: You can also put any part of your document into another `.tex` and say `\input{<filename>}`.

Comment: @leandriis Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to separate the commands that define your acronyms from the rest of your document, you might want to use `\loadglsentries[<type>]{<filename>}` to load an external file that contains the glossary entry definitions as described in section '4.6 Loading Entries From a File' of the `glossaries`'s user manual.

Alternatively, you can also use `\input` to load the file, while the use of `\include` is discouraged.

If your definition file gets too large, you might as well consider using [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls?), a 'Java com­mand line ap­pli­ca­tion that can extract glos­sary in­for­ma­tion stored in a .bib file and con­vert it into glos­sary en­try def­i­ni­tion com­mands'  in combination with [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra). To organize the glossary information, [`jabref`](https://www.jabref.org/), a graph­i­cal fron­tend to man­age BibTeX databases, might come in handy.